# The default of contextIsolation is deprecated and will be changing from false to true in a future release of Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I am new to Electron.js. I was following a youtube tutorial for learning electron but this "The default of contextIsolation is deprecated and will be changing from false to true in a future release of Electron.  See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23506 for more information" appears in my console.
My main.js file is given below:

```
    const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

const {app , BrowserWindow,Menu}=electron;

let mainWindow;

//Listen for app to be ready
app.on('ready',function() {
    //create new window
    mainWindow=new BrowserWindow({});
    //load html into window
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname:path.join(__dirname,'mainWindow.html'),
        protocol:'file',
        slashes:true
    }))


    //Quit app when closed
    mainWindow.on('closed',function(){
        app.quit();
    })
    //build menu from template
    const mainMenu=Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
    //insert menu
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);
});

//handle create add window
function createAddWindow(){
    //create new window
    addWindow=new BrowserWindow({
        width:300,
        height:200,
        title:'add shopping list item'
    });
     //load html into window
     addWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname:path.join(__dirname,'addWndow.html'),
        protocol:'file',
        slashes:true
    }));
    //Garbage collection handle
    addWindow.on('close',function(){
        addWindow=null;
    })
}



//Create Menu template
const mainMenuTemplate=[
    {
        label:'File',
        submenu:[
            {
                label:'Add Item',
                click(){
                    createAddWindow();
                }
            },
            {
                label:'Clear Items'
            },
            {
                label:'Quit',
                accelerator:process.platform== 'darwin' ? 'command+Q' : 'ctrl+Q',
                click(){
                    app.quit();                }
            },
            
        ]
    
    }
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just a deprecation warning, it doesn't affect any of your code. Since you're not setting a value for `contextIsolation` explicitly, the default one is used, and once it is changed your app will not function the same way any more.

`contextIsolation` is an option that can be passed in `webPreferences` for a `BrowserWindow`, like this:

```js
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    contextIsolation: true
  }
});
```

The Electron team decided to show this warning because `contextIsolation` is an option that deeply changes how Electron windows work. By default, Node globals are programatically stripped from the renderer context before executing scripts attached to the HTML page (after executing the preload script), which leaves some vulnerabilities open (such as the ones demonstrated [here](https://blog.doyensec.com/2019/04/03/subverting-electron-apps-via-insecure-preload.html)).

`contextIsolation` ensures that the two contexts (the preload scripts and the renderer scripts) remain fully isolated, save for APIs explicitly exposed through `contextBridge`. It's recommended to use `contextIsolation` unless you're definitively not loading any external content, which is why the default value will be changed. [More on Electron security](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security).

Comment: thanks for your answer but I already use this in my createAddWindow() function inside webpreferences but still appearing in my terminal. Can you please tell me why and how to get rid of this?

Comment: @rafshanulhoquesiam Your `mainWindow` is created without any options. I also don't see any `webPreferences` in the `createAddWindow` function so you may need to update the snippet.

Comment: I confirm that setting "contextIsolation: true" doesn't prevent from getting that warning.